# Error in creating spring starter project STS 4

Tags: spring-tools-4

I have installed STS4 IDE and when i'm trying to create spring starter project , then error like "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" is thrown. I have tried multiple solutions like adding SSL certificate for "start.spring.io" in java keystore , still issue persists. I have same setup on other laptop there it is working fine , but on one laptop it's not working even thought having same JDK and STS version[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vniwy.png)
#spring-tools-4

Comment: The default installation of STS4 for Eclipse comes with a JDK embedded in the installation - just in case this is different across the installations.